# A good way to map a key with a generic type in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, containers, generic-programming

I'm tring to map a key with a "generic" value, and by that I mean that it could be an int, float, char, string, and so on.

In particular I am tring to do this because I receive converted CAN data in the model, and the possible types are (currently) int, float and string.

The first idea was to create an abstract object that could be implemented in different ways (one for each device type), then place it in a container (map or set).

Than I tought it would be more light and efficient to use as value a "generic type", so that as data comes from the CAN bus, the container would be automatically built without creating new ad-hoc objects.

Currently I have tried to use an unordered_map in this way:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> devicesMap;
```

but I realized that it is only available in the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) version of C++.

I was wondering if there is a good solution for that situation.

Comment: You can use `boost::any`

Comment: There's always `variant` if you know the set of possible types up front, but adding new types later can potentially be a hassle. Classic OO polymorphism makes adding new types easy, but operations hard. That also applies to libraries like `dyno`. `any` sacrifices the fact that these types share anything in common, so it's not ideal very often.

Comment: CAN bus - you mean the automotive CAN bus?

Comment: @chris isn't `std::variant` also C++ 17? OP seems to hint at avoiding C++ 17.

Comment: @keith, As with `std::any`, there's a Boost implementation and standalone libraries that implement these vocabulary types for earlier standard versions (for example, [Michael Park's](https://github.com/mpark/variant)).

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<void>` would be one way, not saying it's great, but it's a way.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I will try `boost:any` and `variant`.
@Yakk Yes, i mean automotive CAN bus.

Comment: @chris good point :-)